# Pausing Swingworker

Tags: java, swing, swingworker

I hava a GUI that has a button that need to be pressed periodically in the sense it should pause in between. But i am not able to do that. I have tried with Thread.sleep(). Below is the code.

```
protected Object doInBackground() throws Exception {

            while(true){
                 btnSend.doClick();
                  try { 
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                    continue;
                } catch (InterruptedException e1) {

                }
              }

    return null;
}
```

Can anyone tell me where i am going wrong and how to solve it?

Comment: "how to solve" *what*? what's happening with what you've written?

Comment: @drewmoore Ah...sorry for missing that out...Actually button click does not happen after every 2 seconds. It happens only the first time and it gets stopped.

Comment: is an `InterruptedException` being thrown? You don't know because you have an empty catch block there. At the very least, put a `println()` statement in there to let you know that's what happened. Put another one inside the `try` block, and another after the `while` block, and you can see what's going on. That's how you figure these things out. All that is general advice. In this specific case - see @Hovercraft's answer

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't use a SwingWorker for this since you should not call `doClick()` off the event thread. If al you want to do is make this call intermittently, then simply use a Swing Timer for calls that need to be done intermittently and *on the event thread*.

```
int timerDelay = 2000;

new Timer(timerDelay, new ActionListener() {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    btnSend.doClick();
  }
}).start();
```

---

**Edit**
You ask in comment:

> But i need to update another UI on that button click event. If i dont use swingworker the other UI will freeze. I have to use swingworker. Is it possible to do so?

You've got it wrong, I fear. The button click and GUI code should all be on the EDT. Any background non-GUI code that is generated by the button click's ActionListener should be done in a SwingWorker but not the click itself.

e.g.,

elsewhere

```
btnSend.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    new SwingWorker<Void, Void>() {
      public Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
        //.....
        return null;
      }
    }
  }
});
```

If you need more specific advice regarding your situation, then you'll want to  consider creating and posting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example Program](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) where you condense your code into the smallest bit that still compiles and runs, has no outside dependencies (such as need to link to a database or images), has no extra code that's not relevant to your problem, but still demonstrates your problem.

Comment: But i need to update another UI on that button click event. If i dont use swingworker the other UI will freeze. I have to use swingworker. Is it possible to do so?

Comment: @Soujanya: please see edit to edit. Also, I see that you've already received the [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) recommendation in comments to [your question from yesterday](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24634169/jtextarea-returning-null-to-console). It's a very good recommendation and one a strongly urge you to look over and consider.